# Does invertible diagonalizable matrix have its inverted matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

From invertibility, $(PAP^{-1})^{-1}=PA^{-1}P^{-1}=D^{-1}$, the thing is how do you make sure the $P$ doesn't change?

Comment: You proved in your question that $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are diagonalizable in the same basis.

Comment: "*How do you make sure the $P$ doesn't change*".  What do you mean?  You are aware that $(\color{red}{A}B\color{blue}{C})^{-1}=\color{blue}{C^{-1}}B^{-1}\color{red}{A^{-1}}$ yes?  So $(\color{red}{P} A\color{blue}{P^{-1}})^{-1}= (\color{blue}{P^{-1}})^{-1} A^{-1} \color{red}{P^{-1}}=PA^{-1}P^{-1}$

Answer (score 0):

You've essentially proved that $P$ doesn't change.  I'm assuming that your $A$ matrix is the original, invertible, diagonalizable matrix, and $D$ is the diagonal matrix.  So, writing what you did in a different way,

$$
A^{-1} = (PDP^{-1})^{-1} = (P^{-1})^{-1}D^{-1}P^{-1} = PD^{-1}P^{-1}
$$

Hence you have expressed the inverse matrix in the form

$$
A^{-1} = P\tilde{D}P^{-1}
$$ where $\tilde{D}$ is a diagonal matrix and $P$ is the same matrix of eigenvectors as before. This is the beauty of diagonalization - all you have to do is invert a diagonal matrix $D$, which is easy - you don't have to touch the $P$ matrix.